# R tmap-package legend title in tm_lines and

Tags: r, gis, tmap

I'm trying to build a map with "tm_lines" -element *without* a legend title. There doesn't seem to be an option for the removing the title of the legend. An example with World and Rivers datasets:

```
tm_shape(World) +
tm_fill() +
tm_shape(rivers) +
tm_lines(col="black", lwd="scalerank", scale=2, title="")
```

This produces a map with a legend with a title of the variable name "scalerank". Is it possible to produce the same map without the variable name title ("scalerank" in this case) in the legend? With other tm-functions like "tm_dots()" it is possible to alter the legend title with just "title=", which doesn't seem to exist for "tm_lines" (not for tm_symbols either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `title.lwd` argument of `tm_lines`:

```
library(tmap)
data(World, metro, rivers)

tm_shape(World) +
tm_fill() +
tm_shape(rivers) +
tm_lines(col="black", lwd="scalerank", scale=2, title.lwd="")
```

[image]